# Chrome & Firefox: pictures stick together

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, google-chrome, firefox

I got a problem by my new [website](http://bit.ly/1e5yiO9).
Some pictures of a grid are stick together, but only in Firefox and Chrome.
And if I zoom in to maybe 110% and zoom out to 100% the problem not appears.
Also if I clear the cache and reload the problem isnt there.

Does anyone of you have a idea to solve the problem.

And there a picture of the problem:
[image]

I belive there is a problem with the `masonry.js`. But I have no idea how to fix that.

```
(function ($) {
    var $container = $('.masonry_wrapper'),
        colWidth = function () {
            var w = $container.width(), 
                columnNum = 1,
                columnWidth = 0;
            if (w > 1200) {
                columnNum  = 5;
            } else if (w > 900) {
                columnNum  = 4;
            } else if (w > 600) {
                columnNum  = 3;
            } else if (w > 300) {
                columnNum  = 2;
            }
            columnWidth = Math.floor(w/columnNum);
            $container.find('.item').each(function() {
                var $item = $(this),
                    multiplier_w = $item.attr('class').match(/item-w(\d)/),
                    multiplier_h = $item.attr('class').match(/item-h(\d)/),
                    width = multiplier_w ? columnWidth*multiplier_w[1]-4 : columnWidth-4,
                    height = multiplier_h ? columnWidth*multiplier_h[1]*0.5-4 : columnWidth*0.5-4;
                $item.css({
                    width: width,
                    height: height
                });
            });
            return columnWidth;
        }

        function refreshWaypoints() {
            setTimeout(function() {
            }, 1000);   
        }

        $('nav.portfolio-filter ul a').on('click', function() {
            var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
            $container.isotope({ filter: selector }, refreshWaypoints());
            $('nav.portfolio-filter ul a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            return false;
        });

        function setPortfolio() { 
            setColumns();
            $container.isotope('reLayout');
        }

        isotope = function () {
            $container.isotope({
                resizable: true,
                itemSelector: '.item',
                masonry: {
                    columnWidth: colWidth(),
                    gutterWidth: 0
                }
            });
        };
    isotope();
    $(window).smartresize(isotope);

}(jQuery));
```

Sorry about my english.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score -1):

It may be because you have connected masonry instead isotope